# Windows 8 Metro app, How to set a click event for different images that are loaded?

Tags: c#, windows-8, click

I've created a drag and drop function in my app which i've used a code sample and works ok.
The images need to have a click event, so ive used the tapped event. However I need the event to have a different result.

So basically, the xaml code for the image source is as so.

```
Image Source="{Binding Image}" Tapped="chordClicked"
```

and in the C#

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            source.Add(new Item("Assets/Achord.png"));
            source.Add(new Item("Assets/Bchord.png"));
            source.Add(new Item("Assets/Cchord.png"));
            source.Add(new Item("Assets/Dchord.png"));
            source.Add(new Item("Assets/Echord.png"));
            source.Add(new Item("Assets/Fchord.png"));
            source.Add(new Item("Assets/Gchord.png"));
            availableItems.ItemsSource = source;
            chosenItems.ItemsSource = destination;
        }
```

I tried a few variations on how I could go about doing this but none have worked, I thought the method below would make sense.

for the time being the text block is just a way of testing if the click is working properly

```
private void chordClicked(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (source = ("Assets/Achord.png"))
                {
                    textBlock.Text = "A chord clicked";
                }


private void dragItem(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e) 
{ 
    draggedItem = (Item)e.Items[0]; 
} 

private void dropItemDestination(object sender, DragEventArgs e) 
{ 
    source.Remove(draggedItem); 
    destination.Insert(0, draggedItem); 
} 

private void dropItemSource(object sender, DragEventArgs e) 
{ 
    destination.Remove(draggedItem); 
    source.Add(draggedItem); 
}
```

Thank you in advance

- Bash.d

Hi thanks for your help,
I searched around other places and eventually found the solution on the msdn forums.

```
private void chordClicked(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var source = ((sender as Image).Source as BitmapImage).UriSource.LocalPath;
            if (source == "/Assets/Achord.png")
            {
                textBlock.Text = "A chord clicked";
            }
            else if (source == "/Assets/Bchord.png")
            {
                textBlock.Text = "B chord clicked";
            }
            else if (source == "/Assets/Cchord.png")
            {
                textBlock.Text = "C chord clicked";
            }

        }
```

Which works fine.

I appreciate your help a lot, I will learn more about using delegates and lambdas at some point in the near future

Comment: If you have recurring items, meaning they don't change during runtime, you could actually use anonymous delegates or lambdas.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand, I'm not exactly the most knowledgable programmer

Comment: If you are really want to program Windows 8 apps, you will need to get an idea of lambdas and especially delegates as they server as base for events and other neat stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where anonymous delegates or lambdas come in handy:

```
Image chordA = new Image(); //
...
chordA.Tapped += (sender, e) => { //lambda
   //do what you want with chord A
   textBlock.Text = "A chord clicked";
}
```

OR

```
Image chordA = new Image(); //
...
chordA.Tapped += delegate (object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) { //anonymous delegate
   //do what you want with chord A
   textBlock.Text = "A chord clicked";
}
```

When creating your chords, simply assign an anonymous delegate or lambda. You can specify in each anonymous method what is to happen to your particular chord.

See [lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) and [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: So where I load the image originally like 
source.add(new item("Assets/Achord.png")

I would represent that image as the examples you provided

Comment: Yes, where you create your images you can assign an anonymous eventhandler for the `Tapped`-event. This way, you don't have to write 6 or 8 different event-handlers, but you can use anonymous delegates or lambdas.

Comment: Ok, so i'm still struggling, I understand what your saying.
Im struggling to understand how I use the Image chordA = new Image(); is it creating an instance for the image called in the line
 source.Add(new Item("Assets/Achord.png"));

sorry I haven't been coding with c# for long

Comment: I am not sure what you are really up for... Say it like this: you want to be able to tap an image (apparently a guitar-chord). The time you create the image you must link its `Tapped`-event to a delegate. If you can avoid it, don't use anonymous objects in `source.Add()`, but rather named objects and then add them. Maybe you should post some more code if you can't follow.

Comment: The only other code I have are the handlers for the drag and drop.
If it helps though,

private void dragItem(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            draggedItem = (Item)e.Items[0];
        }

        private void dropItemDestination(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            source.Remove(draggedItem);
            destination.Insert(0, draggedItem);
        }
        private void dropItemSource(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            destination.Remove(draggedItem);
            source.Add(draggedItem);
        }

Comment: Please put it into your question. Tell me about your progress tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some coding which allows for Image click using two images.  This is based on Visual Studio 2015 with update 1 and using C#...  What in fact I made was a two-way switch using two .png files (red & green) which when the image is clicked it turns to green.  One can use this coding for a multitude of programming ways (on/off - activate/deactivate and much more). Hope it makes good use to anyone.  By adding additional lines of code, one can use this as an advanced switching system - for example, chapters of a book (click once for chapter 1 and so on --- the scope is ones imagination), Johnny Smith, Isle of Bressay, Shetland Islands UK.

```
    private void MyBox_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var image = sender as Image;
        var bitmapImage = image?.Source as BitmapImage;
        if (bitmapImage != null)
        {
            var source = bitmapImage.UriSource.LocalPath;
            if (source == "/Assets/Green1 (Custom).png")
            {
                MyBox.Source = new BitmapImage() { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Red1 (Custom).png", UriKind.Absolute) };

            }
            else if (source == "/Assets/Red1 (Custom).png")
            {
                MyBox.Source = new BitmapImage() { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Green1 (Custom).png", UriKind.Absolute) };

            }
        }
```